# How to access code on the next run loop in Android 4+?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android 4+ app. A button toggles the visibility of a View within `ScrollView` between `GONE` and `VISIBLE`. When the views visibility is set to `VISIBLE` the `ScrollView` should move it into view.

This would be no problem using `toggleView.getTop()` how ever this always returns 0 when being called directly after `toggleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

I assume that the view is only added to the layout at the and of the current run loop and that thus the `top` value is only available at the beginning of the next run loop.

What is the best method to delay the scrolling to the next run loop?

EDIT:

The layout is defined in simple XML file:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UseCompoundDrawables,UselessParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 

        <!-- Top Container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 

            <Button... />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Hidden Container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hiddenContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 

            ... Some Content ...

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Bottom Container -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 

            ... Some Content ...

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

When the view is loaded the `hiddenContainer` is hidden by setting its visibility: `hiddenContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

When the toggle Button is pressed the container is re-set to visible and the scrollView should scroll the container into place:

```
...
@Override
public void onClick(View clickedButton) {
    hiddenContainer.setVisibility(hiddenContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? VIEW.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

    // If toggled from GONE -> VISIBLE both values are 0
    // If toggled from VISIBLE -> GONE the values are correct (e.g. height = 300)
    int top = hiddenContainer.getTop();
    int height = hiddenContainer.getHeight();

    if (hiddenContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        int scrollPosition;
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: Invoking an action in the next loop cycle is quite straightforward. Just create a Handler and invoke post method with a runnable anonymous implementation. `new Handler().post(new Runnable() { ... }`. However i don't think this is the root couse of your problem. Could you please share how you add view to the scrollview

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the answer to show how the views are handled.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my side. The top and height values are the same for both modes. Does it happen only for Android 4.* versions? Also it's not quite clear if you forget to set `scrollPosition` variable in your code, or it's just an example?